# WCF webHttpBinding with file metadata

Tags: android, wcf

I am using an Android client to upload files to a wcf service.
The upload is working, but now I want to get the name of the file and another integer parameter into the request.

How can I do this? afaik, I can not use a message contract since I am not packaging the message as SOAP. Is there an alternative?

I use this code on the Android side:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(serviceAddress +
                "/Upload/");
        ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "forest.jpg");

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("step", new StringBody("1"));
        reqEntity.addPart("fileName", new StringBody("elad.jpg"));
        reqEntity.addPart("file", bab);
        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String sResponse;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            s = s.append(sResponse);
```

and this code on the wcf side (just for teesting):

```
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST", BodyStyle= WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    public void Upload(Stream fileStream)
    {
        FileStream targetStream = null;
        string uploadFolder = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Upload\test.jpg";
        using (targetStream = new FileStream(uploadFolder, FileMode.Create,
            FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            const int bufferLen = 65000;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
            int count = 0;
            while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
            {
                targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            targetStream.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an additional parameter other than the `Stream` one in the URI. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx has an example of a service with that.